# Why is the 5960x Haswell and not Broadwell?

Tags: cpu

I was under the impression (and therefore very confused) that the 5960x was 5th generation and Broadwell, and that the 6960x would be 6th generation and Skylake (since they start with 5 and 6 respectively like their other CPUs do).  It seems Intel does things a little different with their extreme series CPUs and it's confusing and odd...I would like to point out that the first number in the model number of Intel's CPU's indicate which generation (or which micro-architecture, to the best of my knowledge) the CPU is a part of.  If it starts with a 4, it's 4th generation, if it starts with a 5, it's 5th generation, if it starts with a 6, it's 6th generation.  Please see the following for my source on this information:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html

I've tried Googling it, and nobody offered any kind of explanation for this.  So I really just would like to know more about why they do this.  More specifically, and straight to the point, why do their extreme CPU's use previous generation micro-architecture and months after the latest generation launches?  John is confused!

I.e.: Skylake just launched, and the 6960x will apparently be out Q1 2016 or so, but it will be 5th generation broadwell, months after Skylake was introduced.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

The 5960x is haswell 22nm process, voltage regulation on board, X99 chipset , ddr4  3rdQ 2014

The 6960x is a *haswell like* Broadwell with **14nm** process , voltage regulation still on board, compatable with X99 chipset , same socket , ddr4  1stQ2016

Skylake, 14nm process, voltage regulation moved back to motherboard only, not x99 compatable, **new chipset , new socket**.  2017

Please edit anything else, as far as what is odd, I do not know. It says the broadwell release was held up, so that is one reason why skylake might be out at mostly the same time.

"For the Intel Core processors based on Haswell, they are marketed as the **4th** generation of Core i3, i5, and i7." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture)

"Broadwell is Intel's codename for the 14 nanometer die shrink of its Haswell microarchitecture. It is a "tick" in Intel's tick-tock principle as the next step in semiconductor fabrication" **5th** gen. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadwell_(microarchitecture)

"Skylake is a microarchitecture redesign using an already existing process technology, serving as a "tock" " **6th** gen. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)

Comment: I don't understand how you can't see what's odd.  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html

Their model numbers correspond to which generation.  i.e.: 4790k, 4790, 4790S, 4790T, etc. are all fourth generation.  Every single CPU on the very first page you've linked (which I've visited countless times, as well as the Broadwell, and Skylake wiki pages) has the format of 4xxx followed by an alpha suffix EXCEPT for the three enthusiasts models.  5xxx followed by an alpha suffix.  I've done a lot of searching on this, and just haven't found any answer.

Comment: I'm re-reading your answer though to see if I'm missing something, because there's a good chance the answer is in there.  But you did make it clear that you didn't understand why I'm confused, so I wanted to clarify.

Comment: The 5960x that the original poster specifically mentioned is a **22nm** (Haswell, 4th Gen.) part (see [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/82930/Intel-Core-i7-5960X-Processor-Extreme-Edition-20M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz)) when the 5* series should be 5th Gen.